# How to get Panels to override node with "no extras"

Tags: panels, 7

I'm having a problem with the node/%node use of Panels. I would like to display the body content of a node in one pane and all the extra fields which I have added into the content type in another.

The problem I'm hitting is the "no extras" option in the Pane settings makes no difference - all the fields (body and extra fields) are always displayed.

Searching around the web, nobody else seems to have this issue. Since it is what panels is supposed to be good at, I think I'm missing something. I've tried using the panels wizard and doing this manually. I had it working in Panels 1 in D5 :(

I'm using D7 and Panels 3.

Any suggestions gratefully received!

Edward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is (I think) that when you added content (Whichever Variant -> Content -> Gear -> add content) you clicked Node and then Node content.  Node Content will display all of the content of the node (Title, Body, and all Fields).  If you just want to display the body choose Node body.

Then in another Pane (Panel Biggest -> Region -> Pane Smallest) you can add your other fields.

Here's a video that talks about Panels and Panels Everywhere and can help show this in action.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6zMcfTxkhc

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect, thanks. It turns out that this was a mixture of my lack of understanding and an out of date CTools module.

Answer (score 0):

While you can do this with any panels module, the most direct usage of panels for layout of different fields in pre-existing nodes is via the Panelizer module.